# Arrange names of bins by ascending order with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have one data table which contain some data. All data are divided into bins so first bin 400-500 contain number of consumers, second start from 500-600, third 600-700 and so on so forth...You can see data below

```
 data.bins1<-structure(list(Bin = c("400-500", "500-600", "600-700", "700-800", 
    "800-900", "900-1000", "1,000-1,100", "1,100-1,200", "1,200-1,300", 
    "1,300-1,400", "1,400-1,500", "400-500", "500-600", "600-700", 
    "700-800", "800-900", "900-1000", "1,000-1,100", "1,100-1,200", 
    "1,200-1,300", "1,300-1,400", "1,400-1,500"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2013", "2014"), class = "factor"), 
        value = c(10150, 4252, 5495, 4732, 2105, 2184, 720, 350, 
        407, 375, 320, 15404, 8201, 3901, 3469, 2547, 1594, 907, 
        515, 420, 354, 300)), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = "data.frame")
```

But my intention is to plot this data with ggplot2. I wrote code below

```
     ggplot(data.bins1, aes(Bin, value)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), 
    width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width=0.5), stat="identity") +  
      theme(legend.position="top", legend.title = 
              element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
            axis.title.y=element_blank())+
      scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB","#E7B800"))
```

So with this code I can plot bar chart but I have problem with arranging bin. On pic below you can see how is look like bottom of plot but my intention is to have plot with arranged bins by ascending order.

[image]

So can anybody help me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(data.bins1, aes(reorder(Bin,-value), value)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), 
                                               width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width=0.5), stat="identity") +  
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.title = 
          element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank())+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB","#E7B800"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank  you. I do it. But this is by descending order. Any possibility to arrange by ascending order ?

Comment: @silent_hunter I have added an update, please let me know if that is what you want!

Answer (score 2):

I understand that `"bins by ascending order"` mean that they should start at the lowest end of your x scale, regardless of `value`. To do this, one strategy would be to pad a zero onto your values.

You can try this

```
data.bins1 %>% 
  separate(Bin, into=c("low", "high"), sep="-", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(low, high),
         function(x) str_pad(x, width = 4, pad =0)) %>% 
  mutate(Bin2 = paste(low, high, sep="-")) %>% 
ggplot(aes(Bin2, value)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), 
                                               width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width=0.5), stat="identity") +  
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.title = 
          element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank())+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB","#E7B800"))
```

[image]

The labels on the bins will contain the zeros on the left, you can use `scale_x_discrete()` to change the `labels` argument

An alternative is to convert your `Bin` column into a `factor` like (`...%>% mutate(Bin=factor(Bin, levels=c(HARD CODE YOUR LEVELS HERE)))`). This might be the most effective way given you don't have too many levels.